# Could not open library 'vips.42'; Could not open library 'libvips.42.dylib'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

When upgrading from rails 6 to rails 7, and running some ActiveStorage methods locally, I see:

```rb
Could not open library 'vips.42': dlopen(vips.42, 0x0005): tried: 'vips.42' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/vips.42' (no such file), '/usr/lib/vips.42' (no such file), '/Users/st/rails/myapp/vips.42' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/vips.42' (no such file), '/usr/lib/vips.42' (no such file). (LoadError)
Could not open library 'libvips.42.dylib': dlopen(libvips.42.dylib, 0x0005): tried: 'libvips.42.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libvips.42.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libvips.42.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/st/rails/myapp/libvips.42.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libvips.42.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libvips.42.dylib' (no such file)
```

There are a number of GitHub issues with similar: (e.g. [here](https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips/issues/141)).

I am not sure if I need to install the ruby-vips gem or if there's something problematic with my OS / shared libs.

Note [some others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849182/could-not-open-library-vips-42-could-not-open-library-libvips-42-dylib/70849216?noredirect=1#comment125318772_70849216) have reported the same error. I wonder if it could be a bug?

Answer (score 74):

#### If you have this problem on your local machine..

If you have just upgraded from rails 6 to 7, and have `config.load_defaults 7.0` set in config/application.rb, then your app will use vips by default.

If that's what you want, just make sure vips is installed locally. You can install it with [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vips) (thanks to [@timroman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849182/could-not-open-library-vips-42-could-not-open-library-libvips-42-dylib#comment125332646_70849216) for this info):

```bash
brew install vips
```

However, if you don't want to use vips, and prefer to use mini_magick as in rails 6, just include [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44211#issuecomment-1017461170) in config/application.rb

```
config.active_storage.variant_processor = :mini_magick
```

Notes

- Moving from using :mini_magick to :vips will probably require code changes to make your application work as expected. See [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-storage-default-variant-processor-changed-to-vips) for info on that.
- Further reading:

  - Rails guides [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-storage-default-variant-processor-changed-to-vips) and [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-storage-variant-processor)
  - [This PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/44215/files)
  - [Installation instructions](https://github.com/janko/image_processing#installation) for macOS and Ubuntu

---

#### If you're having problems with vips on heroku..

If you get a similar issue on heroku, make sure everything works fine locally first (if it doesn't, see above), then to solve the issues on heroku, try the following 3 steps:

1. Add `gem "ruby-vips"` to your gemfile if it isn't already there
2. Set these two buildpacks (in addition to any you already have, in this example I was also using the heroku/ruby buildpack, hence why it's included as the last buildpack):

```bash
heroku-community/apt
https://github.com/brandoncc/heroku-buildpack-vips
heroku/ruby
```

I *think* the order here matters (if you have other buildpacks, best to add them after the first two). You can set buildpacks like this

```bash
heroku buildpacks:set --index=1 heroku-community/apt
heroku buildpacks:set --index=2 https://github.com/brandoncc/heroku-buildpack-vips
```

3. Create a file in the root directory of your app called `Aptfile` with this as the contents:

```
libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-dev
libpoppler-glib8
```

Notes:

- You may wish to add more libraries to the Aptfile depending on what processing needed exactly (for example, pdf processing). [Here](https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips/issues/219#issuecomment-1006370293)'s an example of an Aptfile with more libraries included. And [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#requirements) is the rails guide showing which other things you may need.
- Further reading:

  - Info on vips buildpack in [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/1200#issuecomment-1024047571) thread.
  - See [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/brandoncc/heroku-buildpack-vips) for vips buildpack
  - See [here](https://www.donnfelker.com/how-to-fix-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-vips-on-heroku/) for information about the apt buildpack and Aptfile

#### If you're having problems on GitHub Actions

Just like other environments (see above) you have to install libvips. Do so on ubuntu using [apt-get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58002908/5783745), by adding this under 'steps' in your workflow file:

```
      - name: Install libvips
        run: sudo apt-get install -y libvips
```

Comment: Something somewhere I'm not smart enough to find wants to use vips. Going with the flow, specifying the variant processor. Turns out I didn't have it installed locally, "brew install vips" did the trick for me.

Comment: This is such a solid great answer! Thanks for taking the time to put it together 

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you :-) It's always so nice to read such great answers!

Answer (score 29):

For Linux users just install using `apt install libvips`, if want to keep using the default load of Rails 7.

Comment: Solved for me, thanks. The error I got was different from the one mentioned in the question (I think because of Linux, instead of Mac): `vips.so.42` and `libvips.so.42`

Comment: On ubuntu, I used `sudo apt-get install libvips`.

Comment: It's works well to docker images too 