# Could not open library 'vips.42'; Library not loaded: '@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib'

Tags: ruby, apple-m1, ruby-on-rails-7, vips

Everything was running fine locally in my Rails 7 application on Apple M1 macOS Monterey, until I did `brew update`. Now I am running into issues with `vips`. I've seen another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849182/could-not-open-library-vips-42-could-not-open-library-libvips-42-dylib) saying I need to run `brew install vips`, but I am still getting this error:

```bash
Could not open library 'vips.42': dlopen(vips.42, 0x0005): tried: 'vips.42' (no such file), 
'/usr/local/lib/vips.42' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/vips.42' (no such file)
```

When I run `vips -v` I get this error:

```bash
dyld[18235]: Library not loaded: '@@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib'
Referenced from: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetype/2.12.1/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib'
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpng16.16.dylib' (no such file)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On m1, homebrew puts binaries in `/opt/homebrew/lib` and older versions of the ffi gem don't look there. If you update to ffi 1.15.3+ it will.

See:

https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips/issues/284#issuecomment-1192157228

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [jcupitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894763/jcupitt) for pointing me in the right direction. What worked for me was symlinking with the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib /usr/local/lib
```